# Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building my first Laravel app. That's my first problem that I can't overcome.

I tried to google something about it, but I couldn't find something that could help me.

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return view('profiles.index', compact('user'));
    }

    public function edit(User $user){
        return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user){
        $data = request()->validate([
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user->profile->update($data);

        return redirect("{$user->id}/edit");
    }
}
```

I want to get through that and update `$data`.

**Edit**

```
public function profile() { 
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); 
} 

public function posts(){ 
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC'); 
}
```

Comment: Does the user have a profile? Can you post your user model?

Comment: `dd($data);` are you getting data?

Comment: use `$user->update($data);` ?? why profile ??

Comment: yep im getting data on dd($data)

Comment: In your question.... So we can read it

Comment: Why are you doing `orderBy` on a `hasOne`?

Comment: You may need to make sure the user has a profile before you update it. It sounds like there isn't a profile attached.

Comment: I can't use $user->update($data); cause the user don't have description table, profile have it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
optional($user->profile)->update($data);
```

You can see the [official documentation of optional() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional) here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot update directly on an instance, you'd have to do : `User::where('user_id', $user->id);`
If you want to "update" an instance, you would have to do : `$user->description = $data['description'];` `$user->save();`

Comment: Or in your case, with a profile relation, try $user->profile()->update($data);

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`if($user->profile) {
  $user->profile()->update($data);
 }`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because the user doesn't have a `profile` by default.

One way you can get around this is by using [withDefault()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#default-models) on your `profile` relationship in your `User` model e.g.

```php
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class)->withDefault();
}
```

You would then need to change your controller code slightly since the profile might not exist:

Change:

```
$user->profile->update($data);
```

To:

```
$user->profile->fill($data)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As it turned out I forgot to create a new empty profile while creating a new user. So i was calling an update on the user's profile in this case null.
Try adding this to the User model and later migrate:fresh your data.

```
   protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->create();
        });
    }
```

This will create a new profile for user automatically.